# Can Siri not be used when lid is closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, siri

I use Macbook Pro (Ventura 13.0.1) with external displays with lid always closed. Can I use Siri?

When open the lid, it works. But if closed, click Siri icon says "make sure the mic is connected".

Comment: idk the answer to this, however, one thing you definitely need to do is update your OS. 13.0.1 was horribly buggy. Current version is 13.4.

Comment: You will probably want an external mic since the microphone array is in the top case, it will be obstructed by the closed lid. Whether it gets deactivated, you can test by going into sound preferences and see if the mic is still available. It could be that the sound level is too low to detect your voice